# Smallest number you can get by adding up numbers in sequence

Tags: code-golf

You a sequence of numbers like this one given to you as a string:

"**1 2 3 4 8 11 19 33 59 154 196 260**"

Create a program (any language) that calculates the smallest outcome you **can't** get by adding two of those numbers together.

The numbers given must be integers, and are always positive.

You can only use each number once.

The answer must be > 0 and a whole number. The given string must contain at least a 1.

Examples of invalid outcomes:

"**1 2 3 4 8 11 19 33 59 154 196 260**"

- 3 *(1 + 2)*
- 54 *(19 + 33 + 8 + 2)*

Example of valid outcome:

"**1 2 7 34 34 78**"

- 4 *(1 + 2 = 3, can't get 4 by adding any numbers.)*

The shortest answer wins, answers can be submitted until october 30th, 18:00 CET.

Comment: I think this would be much much better suited for code golf as there is not much in this task that asks for out-of-the-box solutions. If you change this to code golf, you should consider imposing restrictions to avoid solutions like `return min(set(range(sum(Input)))-map(sum(Combinations,Input)))`.

Comment: This is horribly vague... You need a more detailed spec.

Comment: Can we use the same number multiple times?

Comment: @ProgramFOX yes you can!

Comment: @KlaasSchoenmaker That's a contradiction with the spec, where you've written "You can only use each number once.". It's also inconsistent with your last example.

Comment: Isn't the answer always 1? It's larger than 0 and can't be the sum of two (strictly) positive integers.

Comment: The second paragraph states "...can't get by adding any two of those numbers together", but subsequent examples clearly show 3+ numbers being summed together to obtain "invalid" outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

## Python - <s>104</s> 99

My interpretation:

```
L=map(int,input().split())
k=1
while k in map(sum,[[i,j]for i in L for j in L if i<j]):k+=1
print k
```

I tested it with the input string `0 1 2 3 4 8 11 19 33 59 154 196 260` containing a 0 to avoid the trivial solution 0.

Result:

```
16
```

Comment: _lol_ +1 for "my interpretation". Pretty much summarizes the whole thing, doesn't it. ;)